# Vue + Vuetify server-side-rendering: CSS caused `ReferenceError: document is not defined` in production build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering

**Short**

Happens only in production build (SSR). Working in development mode.

```
err: ReferenceError: document is not defined
at js/index.f9ac44f3.js:1:1647
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.i.e (webpack/bootstrap:50:27)
at i (webpack:/src/views lazy ^\.\/.*\.vue$ namespace object:74:0)
at js/index.f9ac44f3.js:8:7266
at .../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:1768:17                       
at .../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:1795:66
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at .../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:1795:38
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at flatMapComponents (.../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:1794:26)
```

**Long**

I've configured SSR for Vue (`vue-cli`) app. It is working in development mode for me. My commands for generating `vue-ssr-client-manifest.json` and `vue-ssr-server-bundle.json`:

```
"dev-client": "vue-cli-service serve --ssr --client --no-clean",
"dev-server": "vue-cli-service build --watch --mode development --ssr --no-clean",
```

`--ssr` and `--client` are my flags that change some settings for SSR. At this step (dev-mode) I get all the CSS inserted into HTML.

```
<head>
  <style>
    ALL 300 KB of CSS HERE
  </style>
</head>
```

I hoped that when I switch to `production` mode all this CSS will become a separate file with a link to it. Commands used for production:

```
"ssr:client": "vue-cli-service build --ssr --client",
"ssr:server": "vue-cli-service build --ssr --no-clean",
```

I didn't write any changes for dev/prod builds in my `vue.config.js`. The only change - it is now `--mode production`.

I've found such lines in a generated file:

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName(\"link\"),c=0;
var f=document.getElementsByTagName(\"style\");
var h=document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0];
```

What is responsible for writing these lines? What to do to remove them in production build?

**Related**

[SSR build says "document is not defined" for a Vuejs cli3 SPA app using a Vue cli3 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102490/ssr-build-says-document-is-not-defined-for-a-vuejs-cli3-spa-app-using-a-vue-cl)